# How to add unavailable packages to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo, yum

This might be a really silly question, but I'm trying to train this model: https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2 on an AWS instance. I'm using an AWS educate account so I was unable to launch an EC2 instance with a Deep Learning AMI, instead I launched a regular Linux 2 AMI.

As per the repo's machine setup instructions, I installed python3 and pip and tensorflow onto the instance. However, I am unable to run the command:

`sudo yum install -y libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg libav-tools`

(the repo lists the command with apt-get instead of yum)

When I run that command, most of the packages are unavailable. The output I get is:

```
No package libasound-dev available.
No package portaudio19-dev available.
No package libportaudio2 available.
No package libportaudiocpp0 available.
No package ffmpeg available.
No package libav-tools available.
```

How can I install these packages onto my ec2 instance? Thanks

EDIT: I see now my issue is EC2's Linux 2 AMI is running on Centos. I would have to manually install each of these packages (I think). Might be easier to try and launch an Ubuntu server, or Linux 1 and use the docker file included in the repo.

Comment: These are for ubuntu, aren't they? I think there are no equivalent packages for AL2, not for everything at least.

Comment: I haven't gone through the whole list but I realize now that it's pointless to try and force it on Linux 2 when Ubuntu is also in the free tier

Comment: Ubuntu will not have `libav-tools` anyway. Just checked. Will have to install it manually somehow if its needed.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Cloud Formation Template to install the pacakges inside EC2 .In that way whenever EC2 comes up , it will come up with all the packages.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html